# Updating calculated values in Android layouts using SeekBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, seekbar, android-input-method

So, I've been working on an app that has a Plan model with a number of different inputs and outputs, and the layout of the app has slider controls for the inputs and labels for the outputs.  When an input changes, it updates the model, which then runs a calculation, and then updates the views.  I didn't think there was anything wrong with this architecture at first, but even simple calculations seem to run really slowly, blocking the UI thread.  Granted, I do have a somewhat complicated way of updating things:

1. Slider (in a viewgroup subclass) updates its value and sends a message to a delegate (which implements an interface specific to that viewgroup subclass).
2. Delegate (which holds the model and the control subviews) tells the Plan instance to set a new value, which triggers the plan to recalculate its outputs.
3. Once the plan finishes its calculations, it sends another message to the delegate, which then tells its output views to update with the new values.

I've modeled this architecture off of an iOS app that I developed which didn't seem to have as big of a problem running the calculations.

Now, I know that Android is significantly different than iOS, so I'm wondering if I'm going about this completely wrong.  Is there a way to just tell these views to watch the Plan model for changes and then grab the value it's supposed to display?

Another major issue that I'm seeing here is with the slider input.  If I put the model update calculations into a thread, every time the slider changes, a new thread will be created.  These threads (as I've seen) will more or less finish in random order, updating the view in such a way as too make very little sense when you should see incremental changes.  Is there a good way of threading calculations that are supposed to be changeable with a seekbar?

Comment: In order to truly know what is causing your performance issues, I'd recommend using the allocation tracker in DDMS in Eclipse: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html .  Off the top of my head it sounds like you need to use a SurfaceView with a game loop to update the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html)?
Maybe your observed model can perform the update using [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) and then notify the observer.

Comment: This looks like it's definitely an improvement on my delegate pattern, but I'm not really sure that it solves the problem of updating the model in real-time with the slider.  The issue is that there are more or less continuous changes happening when the slider is moved, so pushing the calculation code into a thread will spawn any number of new threads that will all update more or less in almost random order. +1 for observable, but the performance issues still seem problematic with a slider.  Updated the question to emphasize the slider issue.

Comment: Since I've never seen an issue with even updating values on the UI thread, have you tried checking how long it takes Plan to recalculate its values? With the architecture you have in place this will be the minimum time (best case) that it takes you to update the UI.
After that, the only other thing that comes to my mind to update the UI as close to real-time as possible, is to use a queue on another thread, so you don't keep spawning new threads and the updates come sequentially. Even in this case it will never take less time than above though.

Comment: For the purposes of this project, you are right, and unless I implement some sort of queue spawning/culling algorithm, the situation won't improve because of the execution time of the update method. Observer/observable is definitely an improvement on the delegate design.  As it turns out, there's a function call in my update method that is causing a huge performance loss and thus slowing down UI response, and removing that lets everything move smoothly, so I'm just going to rework my update method and hopefully all will be smoothed over.

Comment: Optimising the update algorithm would be another great SO question actually :) Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea of the top of my head:

Instead of just starting a new thread for each update from the slider, you could implement some kind of [`Queue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue.html).

You would need a to have a `Thread` running, that holds the `Queue`.

```
public class QueueThread extends Thread {
  private boolean running;
  private ArrayDeque<Runnable> queue;
  private Thread current;

  public QueueThread() {
    running = true;
    queue = new ArrayDeque<Runnable>();
    current = new Thread();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while( running ) {
      if( !queue.isEmpty() && !current.isAlive() ) { //We only want to start a new thread if there is one or more in the queue AND the old task is not runnning.
        current = new Thread( queue.pollFirst() );
        current.start();
      }
      else
        try {
          Thread.sleep( 200 ); //We need a sleep in order to not hammer the CPU.
        }
        catch( InterruptedException e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }

  public void stopThread() {
    running = false;
  }

  public void add( Runnable task ) {
    queue.addLast( task ); //Here is where we add a task to the queue. The slider (or whoever posts the updates) must have a reference to this thread object.
  }
}
```

Doing this would allow each update to finish before the next is started. I am not sure how it will do in performance. I haven't tested it or anything. It was just an idea.